# Calculus area between graph and x axis

Tags: calculus

[image]

How to solve this question ?

The integral would be 0.3x^3+xc^2 + c
0.3(64)^3 +(64)c^2 +c =0 
c= 78643.2/( -64+c) 
am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

Draw a picture. You will get a familiar parabola, with axis the $y$-axis. Note that the region we want the area of is **below** the $x$-axis, and extends from $x=-c$ to $x=c$. By symmetry, the area is 
$$2\int_0^c (0-(x^2-c^2))\,dx.$$
So we are integrating $c^2-x^2$, and then doubling.  Calculation gives $\frac{4}{3}c^3$.

We want this to be $64$. It is now not hard to solve for $c$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be restated because the area "between" the function $y=x^2-c^2$ and $y=0$ is always equal to $\infty$.

I would restated the problem as follows

*Find the exact positive value of $c$ if the area of the region bounded by $y=x^2-c^2$ and the x-axis is 64.*

[image]

Next, make some sketches.
Clearly the region **bounded by the curve and the x-axis** is the region in blue. The area **between the 2 curves** is the |pink area|+|blue area|.

The area bounded would be
$$\bigg|\int_{-c}^c(x^2-c^2)dx\bigg|$$
$$= \bigg|\frac{x^3}{3}-c^2x\bigg|_{-c}^c\bigg| = \bigg|\bigg((\frac{c^3}{3}-c^3) - (-\frac{c^3}{3}-(-c^3))\bigg)\bigg|$$
$$= \bigg|-\frac{2}{3}c^3- \frac{2}{3}c^3\bigg|$$
$$= \bigg|-\frac{4}{3}c^3\bigg| = \frac{4}{3}c^3$$

But
$$\bigg|\int_{-c}^c(x^2-c^2)dx\bigg| = 64$$
so
$$\frac{4}{3}c^3 = 64$$